# Deleting temporary direction via trap

Tags: bash, trap, mktemp

I have a script which looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e 

tmpdir=$(mktemp -d)
pushd $tmpdir
trap 'popd && rm -rf $tmpdir' EXIT

# Business logic which may succeed or fail...
/bin/false
```

When it exits, it `popd`s just fine, but it doesn't remove the temporary directory. It seems that `$tmpdir` isn't resolved in the trap, but how can we overcome that?

I verified that `$tmpdir` isn't resolved by rerunning the script without `-rf` in the `rm`. That exited with:

```
rm: missing operand
```

instead of the expected

```
rm: cannot remove '/tmp/tmp.Y1SdoY5dSu/': Is a directory
```

Comment: What release of `bash` are you using? I can't reproduce what you're seeing in `bash` 5.0.3.  Could you also confirm that it is _`bash`_ running the script and not e.g. `/bin/sh`?  Using `sh script.sh` would potentially make the script fail at the `pushd`, leaving the temporary directory in place.

Comment: Can't repro on 4.4.0

Comment: I'm on 4.4.0 (debian stretch). Must be something in my enviornment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, it was a typo:

`$tmpdir` vs `$tempdir`

The ACTUAL script I was running was equivalent to:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e 

tmpdir=$(mktemp -d)
pushd $tmpdir
trap 'popd && rm -rf $tempdir' EXIT

# Business logic which may succeed or fail...
/bin/false
```